# Solidity Release Roadmap

Tags: solidity, releases

I am trying to track Solidity releases past, present and future.
Is there an official Solidity Releases road-map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Past releases can be found here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases

Future roadmap, as far as there is one, can be found here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/projects

It might be also worth looking at the [open issues](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues), perhaps focusing your attention on those marked with the [`feature` tag](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Afeature).